# to set dropdownlist value in view when record is extracted in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

working with MVC 3.

I have a dropdownlist which populates Gender with value 'M' for text 'Male' and 'F' for text 'Female'.

Now, when I extract record it is not setting the value as per the record's value.

I have following on code in view.

```
@if(Model != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GENDER, 
        new SelectList(ViewBag.gender, "Value", "key", Model.GENDER))
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GENDER, 
        new SelectList(ViewBag.gender, "Value", "Key"))
}
```

The above code means that when page first loads it has no value for gender field as model is empty so just populate list and when person is extracted i.e. when model is not null it populates and set value equal to `model.gender`. But it is not setting the value. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing an NULL object (your model) to your view ? How many places in the view are you going to write `@if(Model != null).. .` Is that not going to mess up the concept of Clean code. ?

I guess this is how you should do it. You should always pass the model/ Viewmodel to the view no matter it is the firs time (Create Entity) or the Editing time. Some thing like this

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   CustomerViewModel model=new CustomerViewModel();
   return View(model);
}
```

For Edit action, You fill the Model/ViewModel object filled with data.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   CustomerViewModel model=new CustomerViewModel();
   model=CustomerService.GetCustomerFromId(id);
   return View(model);
}
```

and in the View, you use it like this

```
@model CustomerViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GENDER, 
        new SelectList(ViewBag.gender, "Value", "key", Model.GENDER))
```

Comment: yes. I have done exactly the way you told but still it is not setting up the value to "F" female. Alwaysit shows "Male"

Comment: Are you sure `model.GENDER` has a value ?